# async function not returning value

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, promise, airtable

I am trying to return buildings and access it in the promise at the bottom of the script, but it seems like the console.log in the then part of the promise is executing before the getRecord function finishes, and so I can't access the array I am creating.

```
async function getRecords() {
     const buildings =[]
     data =updateTable.select({
        fields:['building_name']
    }).eachPage(function page(records, fetchNextPage){
        
        records.forEach(function(record){
            num++
            //console.log(num)
            try{
             //console.log(record['fields']['building_name'])
             
             buildings.push(record['fields']['building_name'])
            }
            catch(err){
                console.log('hello1')
                console.log(err)
            }

        }) 
            try{
        fetchNextPage()
            }
            
            catch{
                console.log('hello2')
                return buildings;
            }
    },function (err) {
        console.log(err)
        console.log('hello3')
        if (err) {
            console.log('errror')
            console.log(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log('hello4')
        console.log(buildings)
        console.log('hello5')
        return buildings
           
    });   console.log('hello6')
    }




getRecords().then(function(r){
    console.log('test')
    console.log(r)
})
```

Comment: It's not really clear why `getRecords` is async since you're not awaiting anything.

Comment: In addition to not awaiting anything you are not returning anything except in the catch blocks